# Change the state of UISwitch with animation programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uikit, uiswitch

I have a UITableView with some cell's that containt UISwitches:

```
UISwitch* actSwitch = (UISwitch*)[cell viewWithTag: SWITCH_TAG];
[actSwitch addTarget: self
              action: @selector(actSwitchChanged:) 
    forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
BOOL value = [appSettings.lock_when_inactive boolValue];
[actSwitch setOn: value animated:NO];
```

And I also want to overwrite `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method to perform toggling of respective UISwitch:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *cellType = [self typeOfCellForIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ( cellType  == @"CellWithSwitch" )
    {
        UISwitch* actSwitch = (UISwitch*)[[[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath ] viewWithTag: SWITCH_TAG];
        BOOL value = [actSwitch isOn];
        [actSwitch setOn:!value animated:YES]; // <-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        [self actSwitchChanged: actSwitch];
    }
    else if ( cellType == @"CellWithoutSwitch" )
    {
        // other actions
    }
}
```

In both situations, either I click on the UISwitch directly or by clicking on cell, it changes it's state and call's `actSwitchChanged:` correctly.

But in case if I click on the cell, my UISwitch doesn't animate the flipping from one state to another, it just changes its state in a single moment.

So `[actSwitch setOn:!value animated:YES]` isn't enough it to tell to perfom animation?

---

Here's how I set & call configure cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    NSString *EnabledCellIdentifier = [self typeOfCellForIndexPath:indexPath];  
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:EnabledCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [self cellForType:EnabledCellIdentifier];
    }
    [self cofigureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

This is how I configure cell:

```
- (void)cofigureCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    switch ( indexPath.section )
    {
        case 0: 
            // not this
        case 1: 
        {
            switch ( indexPath.row )
            {
                case 0:
                {
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Limit passwords attempts";
                    UISwitch* actSwitch = (UISwitch*)[cell viewWithTag: SWITCH_TAG];
                    [actSwitch addTarget: self
                                  action: @selector(actSwitchChanged:) 
                        forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
                    BOOL value = [appSettings.limit_password_attempts boolValue];
                    [actSwitch setOn: value animated:NO];

                    break;
                }
                //other rows of this section here are being configured
            }
            break;
        }

        case 2: 
        {
            switch ( indexPath.row )
            {
                case 0:
                {
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Lock when inactive";
                    UISwitch* actSwitch = (UISwitch*)[cell viewWithTag: SWITCH_TAG];
                    [actSwitch addTarget: self
                                  action: @selector(actSwitchChanged:) 
                        forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
                    BOOL value = [appSettings.lock_when_inactive boolValue];
                    [actSwitch setOn: value animated:NO];

                    break;
                }
                //other rows of this section here are being configured
            }
            break;
        }
        default:

            break;
    }
}
```

But when I debug step by step, and go through this step:

`[actSwitch setOn:!value animated:YES]; // <-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM`

The actSwitch changes its state only after `[self actSwitchChanged: actSwitch];` changed data model and calls `[self.tableView reloadData];`

May be the reason is that I have two cells with UISwitches, and there accures some conflict between them?
May be there is a better way to get UISwitch from the cell then this code of mine?:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *cellType = [self typeOfCellForIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ( cellType  == @"CellWithSwitch" )
    {
        UISwitch* actSwitch = (UISwitch*)[[[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath ] viewWithTag: SWITCH_TAG];
        BOOL value = [actSwitch isOn];
        [actSwitch setOn:!value animated:YES]; // <-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        [self actSwitchChanged: actSwitch];
    }
    else if ( cellType == @"CellWithoutSwitch" )
    {
        // other actions
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check whether `actSwitch` view got from cell subviews is not `nil`? Can you provide the code where you add those switches to the cell?

Comment: Thanks for reply, i've provided the code.

Comment: [actSwitch setOn:!value animated:YES] works for me and animates just like any other. Works in any IBAction or Void statement.

Answer (score 8):

Just make call to your actSwitchChanged function with some delay:

```
UISwitch* actSwitch = (UISwitch*)[[[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath ]  viewWithTag: SWITCH_TAG];
    BOOL value = [actSwitch isOn];
    [actSwitch setOn:!value animated:YES]; // <-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
[self performSelector:@selector(actSwitchChanged:) withObject:actSwitch afterDelay:0.55];
```

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 4**

Create a UITableViewCell Subclass, with delegate protocol. I added a title label and a switch, like so:

```
protocol CellWithSwitchDelegate: class {
    func didToggleSwitch(on: Bool)
}

class CellWithSwitchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var toggleSwitch: UISwitch!
    weak var delegate: CellWithSwitchDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    @IBAction func switchWasToggled(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        delegate?.didToggleSwitch(on: sender.isOn)
    }    

}
```

In your UITableViewController add the delegate method like so:

```
class UITableViewController: CellWithSwitchDelegate {

    func didToggleSwitch(on: Bool) {
        // This is the delegate function that's called when the switch is toggled
        print("toggled switch")
    }
}
```

In your UITableViewController add as follows to your didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CellWithSwitchTableViewCell
    let settingsSwitch = cell.toggleSwitch!
    didToggleSwitch(on: !settingsSwitch.isOn)
    settingsSwitch.setOn(!settingsSwitch.isOn, animated: true)
}
```